# How to maintain production database with less data and report database with all data

Tags: mysql, backup, transaction-log, mysqlbinlog

We have a large database. We want to remove previous months data from **Prod DB** and keep only 3 months data. We also want a **Report DB** with all data.

**For Example:** we have restored complete **Prod DB** backup on **Report DB** on *01-JAN-2018 00:00:00* on a separate server. Now on 1st of each month we want to restore previous month data on **Report DB** from **Prod DB**. From *01-Apr-2018*, we will start removing oldest month data from **Prod DB**.

We are planning it do with MySql Queries and PHP. We will get backup from  **Prod DB** using table date fields and execute SQL queries on **Report DB** for each month. But is it the right way to do it?

Does MySQL provide any facility to achieve this with efficient way.

**EDIT:**

I want to know that, is there any MySQL mechanism similar to master/salve replication that run database structure/data changes queries on 'Report DB' at a specific time(daily or monthly) but does not DROP/DELETE from 'Report DB' when we DROP/DELETE from 'Prod DB'. So all 'Prod DB' queries(INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER) executes on 'Report DB' but DROP/DELETE queries are restricted on 'Report DB'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep both, but do it slightly differently...

Keep the large table with all the data, but purge it after 3 months.  (More in a minute)

Build and maintain one or more Summary tables for reporting.  These will be much smaller than the main table and much faster for building Reports.  These are kept forever.

For purging, I would use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` to break it into weekly partitions, then `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION` every week.  Details [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).  `DROP PARTITION` is orders of magnitude faster than `DELETEing` rows.

For Summary tables, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).  I often see 10x speedup in report generation.

I have sacrificed saving "all" the data.  You may be unconfortable with that.  See the partition link, above, for an alternative to `DROP`, namely "transportable tablespaces".  With this, you turn the partition into a table (and remove it from the main table, having the effect of `DROP`).  Now this "table" (with one week's data) can be moved to some other place for safe keeping.  Or move it into a non-replicated database.  Or copy it to the server with a big disk that keeps it "forever".  Optionally, use "transportable tablespaces" again to hook it into a partitioned table at the target.

(This could be done by the "month" instead of by the "week", if you prefer.)

Comment: Your suggestions and links are good and we are using most of these. We are using summary tables, monthly partitions and master/slave DBs. Our large master database is causing perfromance issues therefore we want to keep only 3 months data but sometimes we need all previous records instead of summary.

Comment: Actually, I want to know that, is there any MySQL mechanism similar to master/salve replication that run database structure/data changes queries on 'Report DB' at a specific time(daily or monthly) but does not DROP/DELETE from 'Report DB' when we DROP/DELETE from 'Prod DB'. So all 'Prod DB' queries(INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER) executes on 'Report DB' but DROP/DELETE queries are restricted on 'Report DB'.

Comment: Something like [Differential or Incremental Backup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.12/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html)

Comment: What kind of performance issues on the "large master database"?  Disk space?  Insert speed?  Something else?

Comment: There are several "proxy" tools that can redirect queries to different servers; check them out.  Meanwhile, it seems that "transportable tablespaces" (in InnoDB) is the most efficient way to transfer a month's data from one server to another.  What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Yes, main issues are disk space, server cost and read/write operations. Report server will not always be available but it will be enabled for specific time(daily, weekly, or monthly) for backup/merge process and any special report generation.

Comment: Can you please name some "proxy" tools for this???  It is difficult to manage this process manually using partitions and datetime fields of tables. Some tables do not have partitions and some tables contain new INSERTs as well as UPDATEs on previous records.

Comment: We are using MySQL 5.6.25

Comment: I am also looking at [Transportable Tablespace Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transportable-tablespace-examples.html)

Comment: HAProxy, MySQL Proxy, MySQL Router, Galera Load Balancer, etc.